# Spring Data JPA and Generics

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity that looks like this

```
@Entity(name = "encounter_pdf_export")
public class EncounterPDFExport<T extends Encounter> implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long pdfExportId;

    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "encounter_type"))
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @AnyMetaDef(
            idType = "long",
            metaType = "string",
            metaValues = {
                    @MetaValue(value = "FooEncounter", targetEntity = FooEncounter.class)
            })
    @JoinColumn(name = "encounter_id")
    private T encounter;
```

The abstract type that I'm extending is:

```
public abstract class Encounter {

    public abstract Long getEncounterId();
}
```

Here is my Spring Data Repository

```
@Repository
public interface EncounterPDFExportRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EncounterPDFExport, Long> {

    EncounterPDFExport findOneByEncounter_encounterId(@Param("encounterId") Long encounterId);
}
```

I am getting a stack trace when starting up the application related to to the findOneByEncounter_encounterId method:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [encounter] on this ManagedType [com.iimassociates.distiller.domain.EncounterPDFExport]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:130)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:468)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.getTypedPath(JpaQueryCreator.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:46)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:116)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:100)
```

I am assuming that either Spring Data JPA doesn't support abstracted/generic fields? If that's the case, would creating a @Query be a sufficient workaround?

Comment: Looks like I might be running into this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-836

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will be helpful to anyone, but I did get this working.

1. Removed the abstract class and made it an interface with a single public getEncounterId() method
2. Modified FooEncounter to implement the above interface
3. Removed generics from the EncounterPDFExport class
4. Modified the encounter field to utilize the above interface rather than a generic
5. Apparently, I'm hitting some Hibernate bug/limitation when accessing fields within FooEncounter. Accessing Encounter within EncounterPDFExport works OK, though. I modified my Spring Data JPA Repository to look like the following (note the modification from finding by encounter.encounterId vs. just encounter):

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface EncounterPDFExportRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EncounterPDFExport, Long> {

       EncounterPDFExport findOneByEncounter(@Param("encounter") Encounter encounter);
   }
   ```

The Hibernate bug in question seems to be related to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-836.